Engine controls
I have a Kohler 21hp motor on a Husqvarna riding mower engine controls are all messed up for chock and throttle and govner I got it like this don't know what springs are missing and what else is missing or were they go any pictures or help would be greatly appreciated thank you

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! In order to know what it's supposed to have, you'll need the engine model number. This is going to be an engine tag on the Kohler engine and not the tag on the body of the mower itself. Then do a google search and you should be able to find out what you're looking for.
